# Adding more than one grouping of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df :

That looks like:

```
    A  Wave Dept  Ratio
1   1     1    A     10
2   4     1    A      6
3   7     2    A      3
4   2     2    A      4
5   6     2    B      9
6   5     2    B      7
7   5     1    B     12
8   5     1    B      4
9   5     2    C      9
10  5     1    C      3
11  5     1    C      4
12  5     2    C      7
```

I am currently grouping the data by `Dept` and checking each row `Ratio` against all other ratios with the same department and incrementing a count if the ratio value is greater than the threshold.

The code for this looks like:

```
    import pandas as pd
    lowerThreshold=1.2
    
    def main():
        print()
        df = pd.DataFrame([
                [1, 1, 'A', 10], 
                [4, 1 ,'A', 6], 
                [7, 2 ,'A', 3],
                [2, 2 ,'A', 4],
                [6, 2 ,'B', 9],
                [5, 2 ,'B', 7],
                [5, 1 ,'B', 12],
                [5, 1 ,'B', 4],
                [5, 2 ,'C', 9],
                [5, 1 ,'C', 3],
                [5, 1 ,'C', 4],
                [5, 2 ,'C', 7]
                ],
             index=['1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
             columns=['A', 'Wave', 'Dept', 'Ratio'])
        print('df input:')
        print(df)
        
    df['Output']=df.groupby('Dept')['Ratio'].transform(lambda dept: compareLower(dept.values,lowerThreshold))
    df[df['Wave'] <= 3]
    
    print()
    print('df - output')
    print(df)

def compareLower(dept,lowerThreshold):
    print('x:',dept)
    #print('y:',y)
    return (dept[:,None] < lowerThreshold*dept).sum(-1)
```

The output for this looks like:

```
    A  Wave Dept  Ratio  Output
1   1     1    A     10       1
2   4     1    A      6       2
3   7     2    A      3       4
4   2     2    A      4       3
5   6     2    B      9       2
6   5     2    B      7       3
7   5     1    B     12       1
8   5     1    B      4       4
9   5     2    C      9       1
10  5     1    C      3       4
11  5     1    C      4       3
12  5     2    C      7       2
```

I would now like to add an additional grouping that also groups on `Wave`.  I would like to only include in the group if the `Wave` values of the data set are equal to or less than the record Wave.  E.g. if the records Wave is equal to 1 and the Dept is equal A then the grouping will only include records that have a Wave **equal to or less than** 1 and a Dept value equal to A.  If the Wave is equal to 2 and the Dept is equal to A then the grouping would include any record that have the a Dept value equal to A and a Wave **equal to or less than** 2 (so including the records with a Wave value of 1 as well as 2).

So the revised output would look like:

```
    A  Wave Dept  Ratio  Output
1   1     1    A     10       0
2   4     1    A      6       1
3   7     2    A      3       3
4   2     2    A      4       2
5   6     2    B      9       1
6   5     2    B      7       2
7   5     1    B     12       0
8   5     1    B      4       1
9   5     2    C      9       0
10  5     1    C      3       1
11  5     1    C      4       0
12  5     2    C      7       1
```

I have tried to add the new grouping:

```
df['Output']=df.groupby('Dept','Wave<=??')['Wave','Ratio'].transform(lambda x: compareLower(x.values,lowerThreshold))
```

But I don't know how to make the Wave dynamic (as each row has a different Wave value).  There is also the possibility of more than 2 Waves.

Comment: Is your `Wave` only `1` and `2` or there will be higher values?

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks - there is the potential for higher values of Wave

Comment: Also is your expected output starting from `1` or from `0` for the highest?

Comment: Thanks - Wave will start at 1 and increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try your logic here by filling the `Output`columns with the rankings when we remove the `Wave` one by one:

```
waves = sorted(set(df['Wave']))[::-1]

df['Output'] = np.nan

for thresh in waves:
    df['Output'] = (df[df['Wave'].le(thresh)].groupby('Dept')
                       .Ratio.rank(ascending=False).sub(1)
                       .reindex(df.index)
                       .fillna(df['Output'])
                    )
```

Output:

```
    A  Wave Dept  Ratio  Output
1   1     1    A     10     0.0
2   4     1    A      6     1.0
3   7     2    A      3     3.0
4   2     2    A      4     2.0
5   6     2    B      9     1.0
6   5     2    B      7     2.0
7   5     1    B     12     0.0
8   5     1    B      4     1.0
9   5     2    C      9     0.0
10  5     1    C      3     1.0
11  5     1    C      4     0.0
12  5     2    C      7     1.0
```